# iCalendar durations where the duration's date portion ends inside a DST discontinuity

Tags: icalendar, dst, jscalendar

[RFC 5545](https://icalendar.org/iCalendar-RFC-5545/3-3-6-duration.html) and other standards like [JSCalendar](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-ietf-calext-jscalendar/) define a `P1DT12H` duration as one nominal day plus 12 exact hours. Normally this will be 36 real-world ("exact" or "accurate") hours, but:

- If a Spring DST transition happens during the "one nominal day" part of that duration, then the accurate duration will be only 35 hours.
- If a Fall DST transition happens during the "one nominal day" part, then the accurate duration will be 37 hours.

But what if the starting date/time is exactly one nominal day before a discontinuous period?  For example, a `P1DT12H` duration added to `2020-03-07T02:30` in `America/Los_Angeles` where DST starts at `2020-03-08T02:00`. In that case, what should be the calculated local time at the end of that duration?

Is it `2020-03-08T14:30`? `2020-03-08T13:30`? `2020-03-08T15:30`? Something else? Also: why?

The problem is that the naive way of calculating the exact duration would be to add the date portion of the duration using nominal units, then convert that intermediate result to UTC and add the time portion of the duration using exact time. But that intermediate result is an invalid nominal time that's skipped, then the local time of that intermediate value is `2020-03-08T03:30` (3:30AM, not 2:30AM) because RFC 5545 says:

> If the local time described does not occur (when changing from standard to daylight time), the DATE-TIME value is interpreted using the UTC offset before the gap in local times.

So using that interpretation of the spec, the final result after adding the 12-exact-hour time portion should be `2020-03-08T15:30` or 3:30PM.

Is this the "correct" answer according to RFC 5455?  If not, what should be the answer and why?

Or is this an ambiguity in the standard and there's no objectively correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was hoping someone else would answer.  Here is my understanding:

**Two concepts here:**

- Either one has the DTEND and is calculating the DURATION, which as you have established, will vary if there is daylight saving change during the event, OR
- one has the duration and is calculating the DTEND. It is best to do that in UTC for safety sake.

**RE your question:
But what if the starting date/time is exactly one nominal day before a discontinuous period?  In that case, what should be the calculated local time at the end of that duration?**

For calculating DTEND, nominal day at same time takes us to invalid time. If one uses UTC to calc that nominal day, one gets 3.30 am.  The spec says:

> In the case of discontinuities in the time scale, such as the change
> from standard time to daylight time and back, the computation of the
> exact duration requires the subtraction or addition of the change of
> duration of the discontinuity.

I understand this to mean yes, when working out the CALCULATED duration (ie where you have DTSTART and DTEND) will vary depending in the events point in the calendar, as you have noted.

**RE your question
But that intermediate result is an invalid nominal time that's skipped, then the local time of that intermediate value is 2020-03-08T03:30 (3:30AM, not 2:30AM...."**

Yes, however in calculating further I think you went wrong adding the 12H to the local time.  Spec says use the earlier UTC offset, which I take to mean use that to get UTC time, use UTC for the calcs, then convert back.

> If the local time described does not occur (when changing from
> standard to daylight time), the DATE-TIME value is interpreted using
> the UTC offset before the gap in local times.

Note this is the **UTC offset**.   So one nominal day takes us to 2.30am which does not 'exist' in LA on 8 March, so we use the UTC offset before the time gap. -8 hours  which gives us **UTC=10h30.**
Plus 12H gives us UTC 22H30.
If we stay with the -8 offset for calculation purposes, we get local time 14:30.

*It is not 100% spelled out in the specification that this is it. More worked examples to confirm would be good.

Advice I have seen elsewhere is to store times in UTC time, do the calcs in UTC time, then for display, calculate local time.*

**RE:
Is it 2020-03-08T14:30?
Is this the "correct" answer according to RFC 5455? If not, what should be the answer and why?**

I understand it to be 14H30.    I cross checked using PHP, with calcs in LosAngeles and in UTC time before DST & during DST, using both datetime->add https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php  and  https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php   and consistently got that answer.

I think correct is 2020-03-08T14:30 because if one uses the UTC offset as specified and calcs in UTC, that is what one gets.

**PHP Workings**

```
add a nominal day P01D
Before DST:
2020-03-06T02:30:00-08:00
2020-03-07T02:30:00-08:00 with modify
2020-03-07T02:30:00-08:00 add date interval

Over DST:
2020-03-07T02:30:00-08:00
2020-03-08T03:30:00-07:00 with modify
2020-03-08T03:30:00-07:00 add date interval



add a nominal day plus 12 H ie: P01DT12H
Before DST:
2020-03-06T02:30:00-08:00
2020-03-07T14:30:00-08:00 add date interval

Over DST:
2020-03-07T02:30:00-08:00
2020-03-08T14:30:00-07:00 with modify
2020-03-08T14:30:00-07:00 add date interval
```

For checking offset: https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/meetingtime.html?day=8&month=3&year=2020&p1=137&iv=0

Comment: Great idea to use the offset. It solves the problem. Thanks!